# Round edges on low poly object

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I want to make the outline of my glasses frame more rounded without any subdivision modifiers (I want to make this object game ready!) but I can't seem to figure out a way to do so. Bevelling the edge makes really strange subdivisions. Also, manually adding edge loops to smoothen the frame out would take a really long time. Does anyone have a good solution for rounding the outline of the frame?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change faces to smooth. Go to edit mode and press T it's in one of the tabs. Make sure you select all the faces you want to smoothen.

Comment: I don't think it will give any good result with this topology. Why not applying a Subdivision Surface modifier and adding some edge loops where he wants it to be sharper?